# How to show Text at bottom of textformfield after user enter some data in it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-onpressed

[image]

This is my code for my UI

```
Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
           child:TextFormField(
             controller: name,
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: Icon(
               Icons.person,
             ),
            hintText: "First name",
             border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
            Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
           child:TextFormField( 
             controller: second_name,
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: Icon(
               Icons.person,
             ),
            hintText: "Second Name",
             border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ), 
            Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
           child:TextFormField(
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: Icon(
               Icons.mail,
             ),
            hintText: "Email-id ",
             border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ), Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
           child:TextFormField(
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: Icon(
               Icons.vpn_key,
             ),
            hintText: "Password",
             border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ), Container(
           padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
           child:TextFormField(
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
           decoration: InputDecoration(
             prefixIcon: Icon(
               Icons.vpn_key,
             ),
            hintText: "Confirm Password",
             border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Now there is a sign-up button down this, now i want to show a text at bottom of each container after user enter some data and if the data is not according to some given condition like 'password doesn't match' , so how to show that or what to execute in onpressed function in my button.
please provide some code for this.
Thanks in advance.

This is a sample picture , so the text in red color saying 'This eamil does not exist....' how want to show a text like this ..

Comment: do you want to show error while typing or while tap on the login button?

Answer (score 1):

In TextFormField, there's a validator function. You can use that to show error messages.

```
  Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
       child:TextFormField(
         controller: name,
       validator: (value){
       if(value== null || value.isEmpty){
       return 'Name must not be empty';
       }
       return null;
       }
       textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         prefixIcon: Icon(
           Icons.person,
         ),
        hintText: "First name",
         border: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can also wrap your entire screen in a Form widget and use key: property to validate when user click on the button. You still have to pass validator function in TextFormField. Form widget is just an extension of validator function feature.

```
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

 Form(
 key: _formKey,
 )
```

Then add onChanged in your button this code so that without validation the form won't submit.

```
 onChanged: () {
              if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              return;
             }
            // write code to save inputs here
            }
```

or,
You can also add autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always in TextFormField with validator function to validate form on user interaction. This property is also available in Form widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onChanged property.

```
onChanged: (text) {
   
  }
```

Comment: sorry sir, i didn't get how this will show the text as i wanted  @akram

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

You can try either of the solutions

Solution 1: Autovalidation is disabled and only on user interaction, i.e on click of validate button text form field starts validation accordingly.

[image]
[image]

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode addressFocus = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();
  final _validationKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  int validateAddress(String address) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (address.isEmpty || address.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else if (address.length < 10) {
      return 3;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int validateState(String state) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (state.isEmpty || state.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
        title: Text("Example"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _validationKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  /* State */
                  TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    /* autovalidate is disabled */
                    controller: stateController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 160,
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    maxLines: 1,
                    validator: (value) {
                      int res = validateAddress(value);
                      if (res == 1) {
                        return "Please enter state";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    focusNode: stateFocus,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      counterText: "",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Enter state" ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),

                  /* Address */
                  TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    /* autovalidate is disabled */
                    controller: addressController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 60,
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    maxLines: 1,
                    validator: (value) {
                      int res = validateAddress(value);
                      if (res == 1) {
                        return "Please enter address";
                      } else if (res == 3) {
                        return "Please enter minimum 10 characters";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    focusNode: addressFocus,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      counterText: "",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Enter address" ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _validationKey.currentState.validate();
                if (stateController.text.isEmpty) {
                  stateFocus.requestFocus();
                } else if (addressController.text.isEmpty ||
                    addressController.text.length < 10) {
                  addressFocus.requestFocus();
                }
              },
              child: Text("Validate"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Solution 2: Autovalidation is enabled always

[image]

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode addressFocus = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();
  final _validationKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  int validateAddress(String address) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (address.isEmpty || address.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else if (address.length < 10) {
      return 3;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int validateState(String state) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.-]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (state.isEmpty || state.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
        title: Text("Example"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _validationKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  /* State */
                  TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                    /* autovalidate is set to true */
                    controller: stateController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 160,
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    maxLines: 1,
                    validator: (value) {
                      int res = validateAddress(value);
                      if (res == 1) {
                        return "Please enter state";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    focusNode: stateFocus,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      counterText: "",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Enter state" ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),

                  /* Address */
                  TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                    /* autovalidate is enabled */
                    controller: addressController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 60,
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    maxLines: 1,
                    validator: (value) {
                      int res = validateAddress(value);
                      if (res == 1) {
                        return "Please enter address";
                      } else if (res == 3) {
                        return "Please enter minimum 10 characters";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    focusNode: addressFocus,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      counterText: "",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Enter address" ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```